# Javascript empty object

Tags: javascript, oop, object

This is an example of code, from a book called *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition*, that I do not understand.

He is talking about Objects.

```
var book ={
    topic: "javascript",
    fat: true
};
book.topic              => "javascript"
book.["fat"]            => True
book.author="flanagan"; // creates new property
book.contents= {};      // empty object*
```

So what I don't understand is the last part. Is he adding in a new property called "contents" that is empty? Because he is calling it an object and it's confusing me.

Comment: No, he is adding a new property called `contents` and is assigning it a new Object with no properties.

Comment: `book.["fat"]` will give you `SyntaxError`. Use either dot or square brackets but not both of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `{}` is an empty object in javascript which is being assigned to the contents property of the book object.

[Here you can see that we can use functions defined globaly on object](http://jsfiddle.net/EaznB/) such as [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the way the `book` variable is defined. It is an Object declaration. 
In the last line, we add a property named contents and assign it an object declared exactly the same way as book except that this one has no property and therefore is an empty object : `{}`

Answer (score 1):

The curly bracket `{ }` notation denotes an object literal.

The fact that there is nothing between them means that a new object reference pointing to a blank object (inheriting from the base object) is stored in the `book.contents` property.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` create an empty object. Means now this object can have new property same as defined by `book.author="flanagan";`

```
// Both are same
book.contents = new Object();
book.contents = { } ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can create an object with {} notation, called ***object literal*** and you can add what ever you want to this object in future by dot even a ***function*** , in your example in first step:

var book ={topic: "javascript",fat: true};

book object is created with two property ***topic*** and ***fat*** and then this object is extended with ***author*** as String and ***contents*** as an inner object, as I said you can use it for creation empty objects (var t={} //example); 
and if you use

`typeof book.contents // returns "object"`

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a new property of the original `book` object, and setting the value of that property to a new empty object.

Answer (score 0):

He's adding a new property called `contents` of the object `book` which itself is an empty object.

Here is a structure of what it would look like when he's made his changes to help you visualise it.

```
var book = {
    topic: "javascript",
    fat: true,
    author : "flanagan",
    contents : {}
};
```

Comment: So is there another way to say that a property has no value? If one just typed "contents" instead of "contents : {}"

Comment: You can assign object properties in two ways. `book["contents] =` or `book.contents = `. The value you assign to it can differ from a function to an empty object or array to a string or number. `book.contents = ""` now `book.contents` is a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var book ={
            topic: "javascript",
            fat: true
        };


        book.topic = "javascript";
        book.fat = true;
        book.author = "flanagan"; // creates new property
        book.contents = {};      // empty object*
        //The curly bracket { } denotes here an object.
        //will add a property contents and will contain an empty object

        alert(book.contents);   //it will display [object Object]

        book.contents.name = 'Success Stories';
        //adding propertis to the object contents
        alert(book.contents.name);

        /*
        you can consider it as object inside object

        objectOuter {
            property1: value1
            property2: value2
            property3: objectInner {
                property1: value1
                property2: value2
            }
        }
        */       

    </script>
```